# Any workaround for lack of support for PadLeft in EF5.x?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I'm working on an app in MVC4 and Entity Framework 5 and recently came across this exception when executing my query.

> {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String PadLeft(Int32, Char)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}

When I have run across similar errors in the past, I've just made a variable outside the query and then used the variable in the LINQ statement. Unfortunately, in this case I'm manipulating the row results so I'm not sure how to go about that or if that is the best method. Any help would be appreciated. My query is below:

```
            IQueryable<System.String> LEAPrograms = db.Datamart_Draft
            .Where(where => where.snapshot_id == snapshot_id
                && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(where.entity_program))
            .Select(sel => (sel.entity_program.PadLeft(PROGRAMLENGTH, '0'))).Distinct();
```

Comment: Can you make an additional calculated column on the table that pads the `entity_program` with the appropriate number of 0s?

Comment: that's a possibility, but I'd prefer something that is reusable. I don't want to create an additional column for each column that I need to pad if I can avoid it.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I ended up creating a List then iterating through the results. When I do a .Distinct() on the List, it casts it back to an IEnumerable. I'm not sure performance-wise which is better, but with some effort I think a PadLeft could be created for LINQ to Entities that did approximately the same thing.

```
            IEnumerable<String> LEAPrograms = db.Datamart_Draft.Where(wh => wh.snapshot_id == snapshot_id && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(wh.entity_program)).Select(se => se.entity_program).Distinct();
        // create and populate a List (because LINQ to Entities doesn't support PadLeft)
        List<String> PaddedPrograms = new List<String>();
        foreach (var row in LEAPrograms)
        {
            PaddedPrograms.Add(row.PadLeft(4, '0'));
        }
        LEAPrograms = PaddedPrograms.Distinct();
```

Answer (score 12):

It's not too elegant but it does the job:

```
...
.Select(sel => SqlFunctions.Replicate
                   ("0", PROGRAMLENGTH - sel.entity_program.Length)
             + sel.entity_program)
```

Answer (score -2):

I think Gert Arnold solution in elegant. Here is a real solution based on his answer:

```
List<string> samplesWithoutMeasures = new List<string>();
samplesWithoutMeasures = (from mm in DB.MEDICIONESMUESTRA
   join mu in DB.MUESTRAS on mm.IDMUESTRA equals mu.IDMUESTRA
   where    (mu.IDESTADOMUESTRA >= 7 && mu.IDESTADOMUESTRA <= 8) && (mu.ESDUPLICADODE == null) &&
            (mm.IDESTADOMEDICIONMUESTRA == 1 &&  mm.IDPARAMETRO == Parameter.IDPARAMETRO) &&
            (mu.FECHARADICACION >= StartDate && mu.FECHARADICACION <= EndDate)
  select    SqlFunctions.Replicate("0", 15 - (SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)mm.IDMUESTRA).Trim()).Length) 
            + SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)mm.IDMUESTRA).Trim()
   ).ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry, this is nonsense. For you it may be a "real" solution, for everyone else (including the OP) it's meaningless. It has nothing to do with OP's data.